# Joomla - Joomfish Error Blank index.php

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have joomla error since installing multilanguage with joomfish. I'm using Joomla 1.5.11 and Joomfish 2.0.4. Resulting a blank page. How to trace error? since using joomla default error reporting doesn't work. still blank page with nothing. There is K2 component also installed.
Please help, cause i can't figure out the error?

```
[Fri Jun 11 18:07:22 2010] [error] [client 174.237.35.101] script '/home/user/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/*.php' not found or unable to stat
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set display_errors to On in php.ini?  You can check this by going to Help -> System Info and looking on the PHP Information tab.

Also make sure Error Reporting is set to Maximum in Site -> Global Configuration.

It looks like something is trying to include "*.php".  I would try searching your code (use grep or findstr) for "*.php" and see if you find anything.

If your logs tell you what file and line this error is being thrown from, that will help find the problem.